# AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Being a new guy and a beginner to deep learning and pytorch I am not sure what all inputs should I give you guys to answer my question. But I will try my best to make you guys understand my problem. I have loaded a model in pytorch using 'model= torch.load('model/resnet18-5c106cde.pth')'. But it is showing an AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'predict', when I used the command 'prediction = model.predict(test_image)'. Hope you guys understood my problem and Thanks in advance...

Comment: For future reference, include enough code that a reader could reasonably understand what the chunk of code is intended to accomplish and attempt to diagnose your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that the checkpoint you are loading stores a model state dict (the model's parameters) rather than a model (the structure of the model plus its parameters). Try:

```
model = resnet18(*args, **kwargs)  
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()
```

where `PATH` is the path to the model checkpoint. You need to declare `model` as an instance of the object class (declare the model structure) so that you can load the checkpoint (parameters only, no structure). So you'll need to find the appropriate class to import for the resnet18, probably something along the lines of:

```
from torchvision.models import resnet18
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But it is still showing like this AttributeError: 'ResNet' object has no attribute 'predict'. Also I have given model = resnet18() instead of model = resnet18(*args, **kwargs).

Comment: the standard method would be `model.forward()`, not `model.predict()`